# C - Turn String into Int on compile

Tags: c

I would like to know if it is possible to turn a known string into a int during the compilation/preprocessing time.

Imagine I have a string with the chars 'AB' and I would like to turn it into a int like in a union:

```
union StrInt
{
  int i;
  char c[2];
}
```

the `c[ ] = 'AB'` will make i have the value 16961

I would like to do the same but during compilation/preprocessing

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It would be very useful for my application.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Pick one!

Comment: There is no string! A character constant is something very different! And it depends on the language!

Comment: How would it be very useful for your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
On my architecture (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
), this:

```
union {
    int i;
    char c[2];
} u = { .c="AB" };

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", u.i);
}
```

prints 16961 just as you expect. (Different implementations may give you different outputs.)

Character arrays may generally be initialized with string literals.

```
{ .c= { 'A', 'B' } }
```

would be another way to initalize the `c` member.

Comment: But it this done during preprocing/compilation? Or execution? Thank you ;)

Comment: The "AB" gets statically  baked into the binary image, and at runtime you simply access as an int. There's no conversion involved. The value is statically known, but not an integer constant expression (or constexpr in modern C++ dialect). (Effectively, it's not usable e.g., in switches or other places that expect an integer constant)

Comment: Multi-character constants are very badly defined. Not only the length is left to the implementation, but also the endianess and encoding. You should have pointed that out more explicitly.

Comment: Your example is misleading. If `u` was local to the `main` function, you actually invoke undefined behavior as some part of `i` is potentially not properly ininitalized if `sizeof(int) > 2`.  Furthermore, the behavior is endian dependent. It would behave differently on big-endian architectures.